# remove unused css rules in bootsrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstap template, I need to reduce my file size, I realize that there are more CSS rules are unused, I did this using dust me spider, how can I remove all unused rules from my CSS file

Comment: maybe you could download a custom file only with plugins that you need

Comment: what are the plugins? I've visited https://unused-css.com, but they are asking membership, Is there any free plugin or website?

Comment: @RJ10 `dust me` is best solution

Answer (score 1):

- [grunt-uncss plugin](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss) to clean up unused CSS.
- [Helium](https://github.com/geuis/helium-css) CSS is a javascript tool for discovering unused CSS
- [CSSESS](http://razorfast.com/2010/11/21/announcing-cssess-the-bookmarklet-that-finds-unused-css-selectors/) is a bookmarklet that helps you find unused CSS selectors on any site.
- You could try the Firefox [Dust-Me Selectors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/) add-on.